# How to exit cleanly out of a QProcess?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I am working on a python-based project which is basically divided into two parts. The backend part runs some robotics simulation in simulation software and based on the simulation results, it generates a text file and uploads some data to a google sheet.

The whole simulation code is encompassed in a try-except block as given below:

abc.py

```
try:
    
    (run simulation code)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    end_program()
```

The purpose of this try-block is to give the user an option to exit the simulation in case something goes wrong upon which the end_program() function is called which generates the text file based on available data and uploads the data to the google sheet.

This program abc.py has been built into an executable (**abc.exe**) using pyinstaller and I am running it as a Qprocess in the second part of my project which is a GUI designed using pyqt

GUI.py

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        ....
        ....
        (GUI elements code)
        ....
        ....
        sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.output_terminal_written)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.exit_btn)
        self.end_process.clicked.connect(self.end_process_btn)
        self.start_process()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ....
        ....
    

    def start_process(self):
        global pid
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
        self.process.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state)
        self.process.finished.connect(self.process_finished)  # Clean up once complete.

        command = 'abc.exe'
        self.process.start(command)
        pid = self.process.processId()

    def handle_stderr(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        print(stderr)

    def handle_stdout(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        print(stdout)

    def handle_state(self, state):
        states = {
            QtCore.QProcess.NotRunning: 'Not running',
            QtCore.QProcess.Starting: 'Starting',
            QtCore.QProcess.Running: 'Running',
        }
        state_name = states[state]

    def process_finished(self):
        print("Process finished.")
        self.process = None

    def output_terminal_written(self, text):
        self.console_output.append(text)

    def exit_btn(self):
        sys.exit()

    def end_process_btn(self):
        os.kill(pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
```

So, here the `output_terminal_written()` function and the line `sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.output_terminal_written)` make sure that any print statements that would normally be printed in a console will be redirected to a QTextEdit widget named console_output and printed there.

`start_process` - Runs the **abc.exe** in a separate QProcess

`handle_stderr` and `handle_stdout` - Reads the print statements in the **abc.exe** file and prints them into console_output

`handle_state` and `process_finished` - Updates when the QProcess is finished.

**`end_process_btn`** - Now here is the issue that I am facing. The end_process_btn connects a GUI QPushButton element. The main idea is to provide the user with similar functionality as pressing ctrl-c when running the abc.exe from the terminal. If something goes wrong in the simulation, the user can press the end_process button and the KeyBoardInterrupt routine should get triggered (the program ends and data gets uploaded to google sheet as explained above)

However that does not happen. I get the following error and the program ends abruptly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\....", line 950, in handle_stdout
    def handle_stdout(self):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am not sure what exactly is the error here and how do I make sure end_program() is executed before the program gets completed.

Comment: I believe that the problem is that the signal is received by the parent process of the pyinstaller executable, so it doesn't reach the "child" (the interpreted script). Maybe you should consider alternative ways to communicate with the script, eventually avoiding the binary and directly implement the computation in the UI program. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3646

Comment: Well, I tried implementing the computation directly into the UI program using Qthread however that not sure how i would incorporate a keyboard interrupt function to allow the user to interrupt the simulation if something goes wrong.

I tried using ```self.process.start("python", ["abc.py"])``` to call the python script directly through qprocess instead of calling abc.exe. However I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: ```
 self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
 self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
```
Commenting out the following lines does allow the data to be uploaded to the google sheet if the process is ended by the user, but the process still ends abruptly.